# top command in cygwin?

Tags: 64-bit, cygwin, top

I am starting to use Cygwin(64) on my Windows 8 laptop, however, the `top` command is not recognized. I have read online that I need to get the `procps` package, but it is not available on the 'Cygwin Setup' package selections. How should I go about installing the `procps` package so that I can use `top`?

ps. for whatever reason `ps` and `kill` both work so I would think `top` would be included in whatever package allowed those guys to work, but there is no `top` command.

Comment: Many packages are not yet available for the 64-bit Cygwin, which is quite new, but this will improve over time. I'd stick with 32-bit Cygwin unless you have a compelling need for the 64-bit one.

Answer (score 27):

The procps package is now available for 64-bit Cygwin (as of Nov. 21, 2013) using the most recent setup executable available on the Cygwin site. I just downloaded the procps package from the hoobly mirror and now top is available to me from 64-bit Cygwin on my Windows 8 machine.

See: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2013-10/msg00009.html

Answer (score 12):

As in 2017, you should install the package `procps-ng` to get the `top` utility.

Answer (score 8):

You need to install the `procps` package. See here:

[procps: Utilities for monitoring your system and processes on your system.](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=procps/procps-3.2.7-1&grep=top.exe)

Comment: Right, I saw that page many times, but it is just text on a webpage. Where is the downloadable source? Even if I download the source, how do I set it up to install without using the Cygwin Setup?

Comment: there might be a way to install it without using setup, but i do not know it. if procps is already installed in your system and top is not working or cannot be found, you might need to update the package. cygwin uses setup.exe to update/install packages because sometimes even dlls need updating so it has to be done outside the cygwin.

Comment: procps has moved to new url: https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/procps-ng.html

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately at this time it seems that procps does not have a 64 bit version from cygwin.

You can use the 32 bit version of cygwin and install procps. That package contains the top command and more system monitoring utilities.

Answer (score 1):

For those unfamiliar with the cygwin setup program: To download the procps package run the cygwin setup exe and after it finishes searching the mirror it shows the select packages screen. In the View drop down select "full" and in the search box type "procps". Don't hit enter because it will show the matching packages automatically. If the procps components are not installed they will have "skip" against them. Click "skip" and it will offer you an available version. Once you have selected all components  you need hit "next" and the package will install.
Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

When cygwin is installed it asks for packages to include. procps is a package but not part of the default installation. So you can reinstall cygwin and select procps package during installation. This worked for me.